# why does this linear differential equation does not gives correct equilibrium in one limit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have a linear set of equation,

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}= 4 \frac{1-a^{-1}}{a} y(t) - 8 (1-a^{-1}) x(t)$

and

$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = b x(t) - \frac{b}{a} y(t)$

with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$

After solving these i get following set of solutions

$x(\tau) = A_1 e^{-\lambda_1 \tau} + B_1 e^{-\lambda_2 \tau}$
and $y (\tau) = A_2 e^{-\lambda_1 \tau} + B_2 e^{-\lambda_2 \tau}$

Where, 
$\lambda_1 = -\frac{8-8a-b - \kappa}{2 a},
\lambda_2 = -\frac{8-8a-b + \kappa}{2 a}$

and

$A_1 = \frac{x(0) a \left(\kappa+8a-b-8\right)-8 (a-1) y(0)}{2 a \kappa} \\
B_1 = \frac{ x(0) a \left(\kappa-8a+b+8\right) + 8 (a-1) y(0)}{2 a \kappa} \\
A_2 = \frac{\left(\kappa-8a+b+8\right) y(0)-2 b  x(0) a}{2 \kappa} \\
B_2 = \frac{\left(\kappa+8a-b-8\right) y(0)+2 b x(0) a}{2 \kappa} \\
\kappa \equiv \sqrt{b^2+64 (a-1)^2}$

Now in the limit $a \rightarrow 1^{+}$ I get solutions that gives correct equilibrium (i.e. $x(\infty)=y(\infty)=0$) as well as consistent initial conditions.

But in the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$ I get weird solution, where my solution for $y(t)$ does not go to right equilibrium (i.e. $y(\infty) \neq0$).

I dont understand why i get different types of behavior in two different limiting cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the formulas for $X$ and $\gamma$ in the eigenvalues? Seems they are always real, it should show that $λ_1$ approaches 0 for $a→∞$.

Comment: sorry for the typo. X and $\gamma$ are actually a and b. edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a→∞$ the system reduces to
\begin{align}
\dot x &= -8 x\\
\dot y &= bx
\end{align}
and has the solution 
\begin{align}
x(t) &= x_0e^{-8t}\\
y(t) &= \frac{b}{8}x_0(1-e^{-8t})+y_0
\end{align}
and indeed $y(\infty)=\frac{b}{8}x_0+y_0$ is not necessarily zero.

---

With the new insight into the negative eigenvalues one can see that 
$$
λ_1=\frac{8(a-1)+b+\sqrt{64(a-1)^2+b^2}}{2a}
$$
is always positive going from $b$ to $8$ for a from $1$ to $∞$.
$$
λ_2=\frac{8(a-1)+b-\sqrt{64(a-1)^2+b^2}}{2a}
=\frac{8(1-a^{-1})b}{8(a-1)+b+\sqrt{64(a-1)^2+b^2}}
$$
is always positive, with limits $0$ at $a=1$ and $a\to∞$.

Which means that the stationary point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is always stable except in the limit cases which are limit cases. Stability there depends on higher order terms, or here their absence.

Comment: I know this. What i dont understand is in the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$ I dont get right equilibrium. because my equilibrium should always be zero. as the original equation has zero as equilibrium for both variables x and y

Comment: Obviously the equilibrium points in the case $a=∞$ form the full y-axis. Or said in weaker terms, the stability of $(0,0)$ changes in the limit $a→∞$ from stable to unstable.

Comment: it will be very helpful to me if you can elaborate on your previous comment.

Comment: you addition to the answer is not true. it seems you missing a factor of 8 to lot of important places. if you do it carefully, you see that (x,y)=(0,0) is always stable, as long as parameter a is finite.

Comment: You are right about the number constants, but the qualitative behavior was incorrect because of sign errors. Eigenvalues 0 without higher order terms result in non-generic situations.

Comment: no stability is only an issue in the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$, in the limit $a \rightarrow 1$, (0,0) is stable.

Comment: At $a=1$ the system reduces to $\dot x=0,\;\dot y=b(x-y)$. Which means the $x$ coordinate remains constant and the trajectory moves to the diagonal $y=x$. Which implies that $(0,0)$ is not stable, since trajectories starting close to it do in general not converge to it.

Comment: oh yeah i see you are right that in the limiting cases (0,0) is not a stable point. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that $a \rightarrow 1$ makes my equations singular but in the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$, I dont see an explicit singular equation but yet the behavior is different.

Comment: Solve $\dot x=0=\dot y$. In both limiting cases the solution is not a point but a line. There is a kind of stability that says that any trajectory that starts in a neighborhood stays in a -- possibly larger -- neighborhood. This is satisfied for $(0,0)$ in both cases.